# Как реализовать слайд в kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy

Под слайдом здесь имеется ввиду проведение пальцем по экрану смартфона. При этом картинка на экране должна оставаться статичной, лишь активироваться назначенная функция после проведения пальцем по экрану. Имеется пример:

```
#python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import  Screen

LABELS_BY_IDS = dict()

class Action(Button):
    pass
class Test2(App):
    def build(self):
        MyWidgetScreen= Screen()
        MyWidget = BoxLayout()
        MyWidgetScreen.add_widget(MyWidget)
        lab = Label(text='First Text')
        LABELS_BY_IDS[0]=lab
        MyWidget.add_widget(lab)
        but = Action()
        MyWidget.add_widget(but)
        return MyWidgetScreen
    def change(self):
        LABELS_BY_IDS[0].text = 'Second Text'


if __name__=='__main__':
    Test2().run()


#kv:
<Action>:
    on_press: app.change()
```

Здесь приложение представляет из себя разделенный на две части экран, где левая часть - Label с надписью, а правая - кнопка. Нажимая кнопку, меняется надпись. Как сделать так, чтобы приложение представляло из себя лишь Label с текстом, но при этом, проведя пальцем по экрану андроида ( ну или зажатой мышкой на PC, если это так работает) в какую-то сторону, например, вверх, я получил бы тот же самый эффект, что и при нажатии кнопки? Ожидаемое поведение : пользователь проводит по экрану, при этом сам экран никуда не сдвигается, но меняется та часть экрана, которая была завязана на назначенную функцию.

Comment: в сторону: код крайне неидиоматичный: 1- kv должен отвечать за то как виджеты представлены, а Питон код отвечает за логику. У вас с точностью до наоборот: логика в kv, а представление в Питон-коде 2- [используйте pep-8 имена](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id17).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы swipe менял отображаемый текст, [можно Carousel использовать](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import kivy
kivy.require('1.4.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        carousel = Carousel(loop=True)
        for text in ['First Text', 'Second Text']:
            carousel.add_widget(Label(text=text))
        return carousel


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: что за барабашка  повадился на мои ответы минуса вешать без комментария. Если ответ можно как-то улучшить, не стесняйтесь, оставьте комментарий.

Comment: Я тут немного не то имел ввиду. С каруселью можно заранее предустановленные слайды листать. Мне же нужно, чтобы была статичная картинка, взаимодействуя swipe`ом с которой, была бы возможность активировать функцию. Возможно ли такое в kivy реализовать?

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев мы с вами это уже неоднократно проходили: если вас есть какая-то конкретная проблема, то про неё и спрашивайте. Желательно не в комментариях, а в самом вопросе упомянуть реальную проблему. Если вы не слайды хотите реализовать (как заголовок вопроса сейчас говорит и как явный пример в документации Carousel показывает), если вы не хотите надпись поменять по swipe как текст в вопросе сейчас говорит и как код в моём ответе показывает, то явно опишите желаемое поведение (постарайтесь описать его в терминах как это человек видит, который использует программу, а не реализации)

Comment: Переформулировал. Ничего, когда-нибудь я научусь задавать вопросы с первой попытки.

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев метода on_swipe не встречал (`on_touch_*` методы слишком низкоуровневые — можно посмотреть [как Carousel их использует](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/carousel.py)). Близкое — это SwipeBehavior класс из [garden.deleteonswipe](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.swipetodelete) (неустойчиво работал, когда я его пробовал последний раз). Ссылаются на [SO ответ того же автора](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31057457/4279), но это какой-то хак на основе жестов (gesture).

Answer (score 0):

Список всех поддерживаемых событий можно узнать функцией but.events(). Запрошенный функционал укладывается в следующий код.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import  Screen


class Test2(App):
    def build(self):
        MyWidgetScreen= Screen()
        MyWidget = BoxLayout()
        MyWidgetScreen.add_widget(MyWidget)
        self.lab = Label(text='First Text')
        self.lab.bind(on_touch_move=lambda x,y: self.change())            
        MyWidget.add_widget(self.lab)
        return MyWidgetScreen
    def change(self):
        self.lab.text = 'Second Text'


if __name__=='__main__':
    Test2().run()
```

В общем после чтения комментариев переходим к варианту

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import  Screen


class Test2(App):
    def build(self):
        MyWidgetScreen= Screen()
        MyWidget = BoxLayout()
        MyWidgetScreen.add_widget(MyWidget)
        self.lab = Label(text='First Text')
        self.lab.bind(on_touch_move=lambda x,y: self.touch(y))
        MyWidget.add_widget(self.lab)
        return MyWidgetScreen
    def touch(self, y):
        if abs(y.dx)>abs(y.dy):
            if y.dx>0:
                self.lab.text = 'right'                
            else:
                self.lab.text = 'left'
        else:
            if y.dy>0:
                self.lab.text = 'up'                
            else:
                self.lab.text = 'down'


if __name__=='__main__':
    Test2().run()
```

Comment: Окей, on_touch_move работает так, как я и запрашивал. Одно небольшое уточнение, которое я не упомянул в вопросе. Можно ли сделать так, что движение в разные стороны ( вверх, вниз, влево, вправо ) ссылается на разные функции?

Comment: можно использовать события on_touch_down и on_touch_up для начала и конца движения и по изменению координат (y) определить направление [Документация](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html?highlight=motionevent#)

Comment: Что-то не совсем допёр. Если к событию on_touch_down я приписываю, например print(dsx),( где dsx  -  Delta between self.sx and self.psx, in 0-1 range) то мне python выдаёт, что dsx не была объявлена. Как этого избежать?

Comment: не print(dsx), а print(y.dsx)

Comment: В таком случае выдаёт, что переменная y не объявлена

Comment: Покажи подробнее кусок кода

Comment: Давай лучше вынесу это обсуждение в отдельный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709977/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-x-y-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-swipe-%D0%B2-kivy