# Как сменить текущий экран в kv, если он определён в другом kv правиле?

Tags: python, kivy

Как обращаться к тому или иному объекту в нашем приложении?
Пример:

```
#python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class Test2(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

class MyWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Scr1(Screen):
    pass
class Scr2(Screen):
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    Test2().run()
```

А также его kv-шник:

```
#kv
<MyWidget>:
    Scr1:
        name: '1'
        Button:
            text: 'This is screen ONE'
            on_press: root.current = '2'
    Scr2:

<Scr2>:
    name:'2'
    Button:
        text: 'This is screen TWO'
        on_press: root.current = '1'
```

В этом примере 2 скрина. Один включён в MyWidget, другой вынесен отдельно. Нажимая на кнопу у Scr1, мы исполняем команду root.current = '2', т.к. root здесь MyWidget, мы меняем ему текущий экран и всё ок. Однако, делая тоже самое с Scr2, у нас ничего не выходит, т.к. root здесь будет Scr2.

Как обратиться к MyWidget из Scr2 здесь?

Comment: *"Как обратиться к MyWidget из Scr2 здесь?"* -- что `self.parent` в Scr2 возвращает? Стоит явно упомянуть ваши предыдущие вопросы на похожую тему и что конкретно вам не ясно в представленных решениях. К примеру, связанные вопросы: [Как изменить значение текста Label в kivy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706278/23044), [Как обратиться к Label по id созданным динамически в Питон коде (не Kv)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706541/23044)

Comment: С предыдущим запросами всё ок, однако, прошу обратить ваше внимание, что здесь задан другой вопрос. Как преодолеть этот барьер между двумя классами? Ибо, хоть Scr2 здесь и входит в MyWidget, тем не менее ни root.current ни self.parent.current ни обращение по id не могу изменить текущий экран MyWidget

Comment: Хм, разобрался, self.parent.parent.current = '1' здесь будет работать. Собственно, этот запрос и создан с целью выяснить логику обращений к виджетам. Сейчас я знаю только 3 команды - app, parent, root, которые позволяют обращаться к виджетам. Возможно есть ещё какие-то. Я пытаюсь понять, как это работает. В любом случае, спасибо большое вам за ответ, т.к. до него я не знал команду parent и не знал, как решить эту задачу.

Comment: К примеру, если .parent "поднимается" на один уровень выше, то как, например, обратиться к "потомку" и т.д.

Comment: Если у вас конкретная проблема, то и задавайте вопрос именно о ней. Вместо расплывчатого *"обращение к объектам в kivy"*, отредактируйте вопрос и замените заголовок на: «как сменить текущий экран в kv, если он определён в другом kv правиле». Приведите явно ваши попытки, к примеру: root.manager.current = '1' в `<Scr2>`

Comment: `self.parent` в Питон коде внутри class Scr2 возвращает вам объект MyWidget класса (я явно вопрос привёл в комментарии, на который `self.parent` ответом является). Конструкций типа self.parent.parent следует избегать.

Comment: Окей, как избежать конструкций вида parent.parent если виджет, от которого идёт обращение зарыт очень глубоко? Например так : ScreenManager - > Screen -> BoxLayout -> BoxLayout -> BoxLayout > Button. Я бы здесь написал в Button следующее : on_press: self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.current ='blablabla'. Как в этой конкретной ситуации избежать многократного повторения?

Comment: прочтите комментарий с root.manager.current

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что manager - это команда, применяемая к объекту класса Screen, которая "переходит" к ScreenManager, в котором есть вышеуказанный Screen? Таким образом, говоря root.manager - за root выступает Screen и от него посредством manager мы переходим к ScreenManager этого Screen?

Comment: Без проблем....

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснения, пока буду считать, что manager возвращает ScreenManager. Возможно у вас найдётся когда-нибудь немного времени, чтобы помочь мне с ещё одним вопросом - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708502/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4-%D0%B2-kivy-python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы поменять экран в `<Scr2>`, можно использовать:

```
     on_press: root.manager.current = '1'
```

`root` как всегда позволяет получить корень текущего правила. В `<Scr2>` kv-правиле, `root` это Scr2 виджет. В `<MyWidget>` определении, `root` это MyWidget экземпляр.

[`manager` это *свойство*](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html), которое есть у каждого Screen. Поэтому внутри `<Scr2>`, `root.manager` позволяет получить соответствующий ScreenManager.

Изменение `.current` свойства у ScreenManager меняет текущий экран.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что manager - это команда, применяемая к объекту класса Screen, которая "переходит" к ScreenManager, в котором есть вышеуказанный Screen? Таким образом, говоря root.manager - за root выступает Screen и от него посредством manager мы переходим к ScreenManager этого Screen?

Общее правило в Питоне: если объект `obj` имеет `attr` атрибут, то чтобы получить этот атрибут: `obj.attr` можно использовать.

Как правило, `obj.attr` не должен иметь никаких побочных действий, то есть `obj.attr` просто возвращает соответствующее свойство и всё.

Полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""#:kivy 1.4.0
# из вопроса
<MyWidget>:
    Scr1:
        name: '1'
        Button:
            text: 'This is screen ONE'
            on_press: root.current = '2'
    Scr2:

<Scr2>:
    name:'2'
    Button:
        text: 'This is screen TWO'
        on_press: root.manager.current = '1'
""")

class MyWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Scr1(Screen):
    pass

class Scr2(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenOtherRuleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenOtherRuleApp().run()
```