# Как объявить разницу между x, y координатами при swipe` в kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Наличествует примерное следующий код :

```
#kv
<Window_in_Pole>: #Game part(GridLayout)
    cols: 4
    size_hint_y: 0.5
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.75, 0.67, 0.67, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    spacing: 5
    on_touch_down:
        print(y.dsx)
```

А также питон:

```
imports...
class Window_in_Pole(GridLayout):  # Окно, входящее в main part наравне с top part
    pass




class Test2(App):

    def build(self):
        win = Window_in_Pole()
        return win

    def left(self):
        print('It`s left')

    def right(self):
        print('It`s right')
        def up(self):
            print('it`s up')

        def down(self):
            print('it`s down')

Test2().run()
```

Где ## отмечено неработающее место. Необходимо от программы реализовать следующее поведение- проведение пальцем по экрану программы в разные стороны вызывает соответствующие функции. Как найти здесь дельты от перемещения "пальцем" по осям y и x? Вопрос создан как расширенный комментарий для  Evgeny Shmidt(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194338/evgeny-shmidt)

Comment: Возможно, этот вариант вам подойдет в качестве примера для разбора - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144228/how-to-swipe-left-and-right-in-python-kivy-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде работает такая комбинация

```
<Window_in_Pole>: #Game part(GridLayout)
    cols: 4
    size_hint_y: 0.5
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.75, 0.67, 0.67, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    spacing: 5
    on_touch_move:
        print(args[1].dsx)
```

Comment: Что здесь args[1]?

Comment: Я понял, что через args[1] можно запрашивать позиции и проч, но что оно само из себя представляет? Сам объект, что скрывается под этим именем?

Comment: Событие MotionEvent. 
args - параметры обработчика: 0 - источник события, 1 - само событие